# JavaScript RegExp vs ASP RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I use this JavaScript function :

```
 function WR_isValidMobile(mobileNumber) {
         var pattern = new RegExp(/\b([9][0123])\d{8}\b|\b([0][9][0123])\d{8}\b/g);
         return pattern.test(mobileNumber);
};
```

To validate Iran Mobile numbers and it is OK.

Now I want to use this validation expression for ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator control, so my code is :

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="/\b([9][0123])\d{8}\b|\b([0][9][0123])\d{8}\b/g" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" ErrorMessage="Err"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

But it doesn't work.
Is there any difference between javascript RegExp and ASP ValidationExpression? Or do they use these expression in different ways?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.Net regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) are not [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). At the very least, you need to remove the JavaScript regex delimiters (`/`) and the flag `g`. I think the rest of it is fine.